# Cannot get query result from Model to Controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Trying to get result from database by calling stored procedure in code-igniter. Below is my controller & model. Model is working fine getting result from stored procedure and can show the result when I do `print_r()` in model. But I am not able to get the result of query in controller method. Not able to understand the error here.

Controller:

```
function weeklysalesstatus()
{
    $this->data['rpt']  =$this->reports_model->weeklysalesstatus(true);
    $this->data['page_title'] ='Weekly Sales Status [ Residential ]';
    print_r("here...");
    $this->page_construct('reports/weeklysalesstatus', $this->data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function weeklysalesstatus($sender = false)
{
    $sql = 'select * from region';
    $sql1 = 'CALL GetWeeklySalesStatus()';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql1); 

    if(count($query) > 0) {
        foreach (($query->result()) as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
            //var_dump($data);
        }
        return $data;
    } else { 
        print_r("no rows");
    }
    return $data;
}
```

The issue is somewhere in this line : `$this->data[$rpt] = $this->reports_model->weeklysalesstatus();`
But can't figure it out. 
Thanks

EDIT:

These errors arise only when I call Stored Procedure CALL. For other queries it work perfectly. So is there any settings I need to do on Codeigniter DB class for calling a Stored procedure  thru active record?

Comment: can you post your error messages?

Comment: how to display the error message. It is just blank page with no message.

Comment: You can find  "define('ENVIRONMENT',) in index.php. you should write it as define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');

Comment: After that you can see error messages.

Comment: Can you see error messages?

Comment: I am on waiting your response.

Comment: Yes.  Message: Undefined variable: rpt  and  Message: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean

Comment: resolved this error:  Message: Undefined variable: rpt

Comment: still showing nothing on view and showing this error message: Message: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean –

Comment: you have an issue in your model.you should repair your model file. if you are using teamviewer, I can fix the issue more quickly.

Comment: how to send tv id? ..here?

Comment: arnoldbendaa@gmail.com this is my email.

Comment: is there any issue in my model as I shown above?

Comment: Yes, I think it seems like model problem.

Comment: Check output of `var_dump(  $data )` you may find answer.

Comment: As I  mentioned earlier in model it is fetching data from db perfectly and display the result if I do either var_dump or print_r($data).  Only issue is when I try to get the result in variable in controller.

Comment: I figured out the problem is only when I give stored procedure call in query. If I write simple query with Select statement it works perfectly. But when I write call statement for stored procedure than it freeze the screen.

Answer (score 0):

$q = $this->db->query('CALL GetWeeklySalesStatus');

Change this line to

$q = $this->db->query('CALL GetWeeklySalesStatus')->result();

Comment: Receives this error: Message: Call to a member function result() on array

Answer (score 0):

**In Model**

```
public function weeklysalesstatus()
{
    //$sql = 'select * from region';
    $sql1 = 'CALL GetWeeklySalesStatus()';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql1); 

    if(!empty($query)) 
    {
        $data = $query->result_array();
        return $data;
    }
    else 
    { 
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
function weeklysalesstatus()
{
    $rpt  =$this->reports_model->weeklysalesstatus();

    if ($rpt == FALSE) {
        echo "Empty";
    } else {
        $data['rpt'] =  $rpt;
    }

    $data['page_title'] ='Weekly Sales Status [ Residential ]';
    $this->page_construct('reports/weeklysalesstatus', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the controller like the following hope it works

```
function weeklysalesstatus()
        {
             $this->data['rpt']   =$this->reports_model->weeklysalesstatus();
             $this->data['page_title'] ='Weekly Sales Status';
             $this->page_construct('reports/weeklysalesstatus', $this->data);
        }
```

Comment: I am doing exactly the same and then trying different changes in code but nothing works. If I change query from Call statement to Select statement it works. But 'Call <StoredProcedure name>' not working. There must be some unique way of coding when calling a stored procedure in codeigniter thru activerecords.

Answer (score 0):

your model

```
public function weeklysalesstatus($sender = false)
{
    $sql = 'select * from region';
    $sql1 = 'CALL GetWeeklySalesStatus()';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql1); 
    $data["result"] = array();
    if(count($query) > 0) {
        foreach (($query->result()) as $row) {
           $data["result"][] = $row;
           //var_dump($data);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

your controller

```
function weeklysalesstatus()
{
   $data['rpt']  =$this->reports_model->weeklysalesstatus(true);
   $data['page_title'] ='Weekly Sales Status [ Residential ]';
   print_r("here...");
   $this->page_construct('reports/weeklysalesstatus', $data);
}
```